# Has anyone had success with building UWP application using only MS build tool

Tags: build, msbuild, uwp

We've got a build server with Windows Server 2012  being installed.
I've been trying to wrap my head around building our UWP application (windows 10) with means of MS Build tool 15 solely.

My question is, has anyone had success with building UWP application only using MS build tool? Without any help of Visual Studio?

Thanks,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1):

Only tried this on a Win 10 PC w/ Visual Studio installed, but if you have all the right dependencies, it might work on Windows Server 2012 as well:

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;AppxBundlePlatforms=x86;AppxBundle=Always
```

This will rebuild the solution in Release/x86 and generate an AppBundle ready to be deployed to a device. You can start from here and check other options foo platform setting if you need AnyCPU or others.

Comment: I've followed this [tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167655/has-anyone-had-success-with-building-uwp-application-using-only-ms-build-tool/38170084#38170084) , but again there were some required files missing needed to successfully build the solution. Installing  VS 2015 Community with applied upgrade resolved the problem , but it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: You will not be able to get very far with this since a number of important tasks and targets required to build an application only ship with Visual Studio, not MSBuild or the SDK. For example, we have tasks for generation XBF from XAML, compiling the XAML itself, creating AppX pacakges, etc. Technically, you could bypass all of this and hand author the AppX package, but it is going to be a lot of work :). What is the exact scenario that you are trying to enable that is making it hard to install Visual Studio in the first place?